# HTML/CSS Help I cant't position my search box

Tags: javascript, html, css

for some reason my search box is stuck right under my logo every time I try to move it. Here is my code

```
.searchbox{
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

And my HTML

```
    <div class="headerMenu">
            <div id="wrapper"">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="./img/logo.png" />
                        <div class="seachbox">
                        <p style="margin-right: 1px;"></p>
                            <form action="search.php" methond="GET" id="search" >
                                    <input type ="text" name="q" size"60" placeholder="Find Surfers...">
```

My logo css doesn't have position: relative

```
.logo{
    width: 125px;
}
.logo img{
    width: 150px;
height: 38px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You need to post your HTML code as well. Plus rest of the code that is relevant i.e. Logo's

Comment: Can't tell without looking, but my bet is you haven't set it's containing element as `position: relative`. I'd have to see your code to be sure, though

Comment: You need to add the rest of the HTML, as well as the relevant CSS code for the parent elements

Comment: If you could post the relevant code or remake the problem in jsFiddle or similar, it would go a long way to us helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because `.logo` has `position: relative;`. Throw out the searchbox from the `.logo` div. That isn't a part of the logo, is it?

Do something like this

```css
header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
header #logo{
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 60px;

}
header #searchbox{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <input type="text" id="searchbox" value="Search...">
</header>
```